# Powershell report to csv all files modified in last month

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm about to write a PS script to get a report in CSV of all files modified within last month. I've tried two options but first doesn't write report to a file and just showing results on screen and second simply does nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

```
$dir_to_look="D:\TestFolder"    
$month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)    
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate } | foreach {  Write-Host "$($_.LastWriteTime) :: $($_.Fullname) "  } | export-csv -path \\share\filename.csv
```

Here is the second one:

```
 function Get-OldFiles {
 param($date)
 $folders = get-childitem “D:\TestFolder” -recurse | Where-Object {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true}
 foreach ($folder in $folders) {
     $oldfiles = Dir $folder.fullname *.* | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $date}
     if ($oldfiles.count) {
         [float]$totalsize = ($oldfiles | Measure-Object -Sum length).Sum / 1KB
         $data = @{‘Folder’=$folder.fullname;’Count’=$oldfiles.count;’Size(Kb)’=$totalsize}
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Prop $data
        }
    }
}
Get-OldFiles ’dd/mm/yyyy′ | Export-CSV \\sharename\file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Where is dd/mm/yyyy - is a date which I want to specify for each report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first script is that Powershell returns the last statement inside your loop, but your last statement was a Write-Host which returns nothing it only outputs to your console. Fix below:

```
$dir_to_look="D:\TestFolder"    
$month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)    
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | ? {
  !($_.psiscontainer) -and  $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate
} | % { 
  Write-Host "$($_.LastWriteTime) :: $($_.Fullname) "  
  "$($_.LastWriteTime) :: $($_.Fullname) "
} | Set-Content -path \\share\filename.csv
```

Comment: Dave, great thank you. But unfortunately run this script brings nothing to the csv file. Looks like endless loop as script never ends.

Comment: Made a small change to my answer, changed the Export-Csv to a Set-Content. I have tested and it works fine for me. It can't be an endless loop, it will only loop around the files in your TestFolder. Have your tried it with a smaller input set?

Comment: Yes, just tried with a folder which contains only few files recently modified. Looks like it does nothing. Why it's necessary to replace export-csv with set-content which replaces the content of files?

Comment: Export-Csv is for exporting objects to a CSV file, you are exporting strings which don't conform to CSV format. So not an endless loop? Next I would check your $month_backdate variable, the name implies you want to go back a month but you are assigning it yesterday's date. Are your sample files less than a day old?

Comment: It's just a try with one day and yes I'm trying to run this script on a folder with few files modified today and even if I change number of days to 7 it still does not work. What surprising me is that script never ends and stops if I break it manually. And CSV file doesn't change it modified date.

Comment: If you comment out the last pipe with the Set-Content and run it - does it return results to your screen?

Comment: No, it just freezes on last executing the last row.

Comment: All I can say is it works fine for me- you must have something strange going on setup wise. As with any problem you need to break it down and simplify in order to find the issue. try paring it down by removing the Where or making the code in the loop real simple. Maybe try it on another machine. Have tried using the Debugger in Powershell IDE?

Comment: No, I've never tried Debugger before :) Will try it.

Comment: So, the script works but it displays results on screen and writes nothing to csv file. And if file is not created  then script even does not create the csv file.

Comment: I noticed that script renamed sheet name to 'report' :)

Comment: cool so it works? Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Hi Dave, No it was not working. But it does now after I've changed Write-host to Select-object so the code itself now looks:

Comment: `code`
$dir_to_look="D:\TestFolder"    
$month_backdate=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)    
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look -Recurse | ? { !($_.psiscontainer) -and  $_.LastWriteTime -gt $month_backdate } | Select-object LastWriteTime, Fullname | export-csv -path \\sharename\report.csv